# Dual Boot Ubuntu and Windows 10 - Which On my way! First?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, partitioning, system-installation

I have a new SSD, without any OS on it.
I want to dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu,
which os should I install first to make everything easier ?

Comment: It doesn't matter, but to make it easier, you should let someone else do it for you.

Comment: IF newer system with UEFI, just be sure to install both in same boot mode. How you boot install media UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. With UEFI and then gpt, Windows adds multiple special partitions that it wants.

Comment: Note that the duplicate I flagged is about a BIOS/MBR setup. The details do not apply to UEFI/GPT setups, but it does answer the question "Which should I install first?"

Answer (score 2):

Windows. Windows bootloader doesn't play nice with other operating systems.
If you install Windows first, then Ubuntu, grub should pick up the Windows partition during install and when you've finished, you'll have the choice of which OS to boot into.

Just be sure to select manual partitioning during your Ubuntu install to keep the Windows install intact.

And as oldfred says above, make sure you install both in the same mode (UEFI or BIOS)